# Python BeautifulSoup unable to find tags under certain levels

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I was trying to extract website titles and photo links from [this link](https://post.naver.com/viewer/postView.nhn?volumeNo=30729360&memberNo=25831870)

I used codes below

```
webpage = requests.get(url)
page = bs(webpage.content, "html.parser")
content = webpage.find("div", {"class":"end__viewer_container"})
```

However, when I try to extract html contents, I can only print to the level

```
<div id="cont" class= "end __viewer_container" role= "main" style="padding-top: 43px;">
```

For everything inside/under it,for example

```
title = webpage.find("h3", {"class":"se_textarea"}

photo_link = webpage.find("div", {"class":"se_viewArea"})
```

When I try to find it, Python only return "None", I was not able to extract anything under this level

When I try to print

```
content = webpage.find("div", {"class":"end __viewer_container"})
```

I am able the see the elements that I want to find,but not able to extract.

Also,I suspect that there is a script under it

```
<div class="end __viewer_container" id="cont" role="main">
<!-- 컨텐츠 내용 {{ -->
<script id="__clipContent" type="x-clip-content">
    <div id="SEDOC-1613466923574--228885683" class="se_doc_viewer se_body_wrap se_theme_default " 
      data-docversion="1.0">
```

I am wondering whether this script causing me not being able to extract anything inside/under it.

Or are there any other ways that can extract the title and the photos links?

Thanks

Comment: Is it a client rendering issue? Maybe what BS is seeing isn't being fully rendered?

Comment: When I print content = webpage.find("div", {"class":"end __viewer_container"}), I am able to see those elements,so I guess it may not be rendering issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

they put html inside script tag `<script type="x-clip-content" id="__clipContent">...` this is why you can't select the element.

the solution is to get innerHTML inside `#__clipContent` then re-parse with BeautifulSoup

```
webpage = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage.text, 'html.parser')
clipContent = soup.select_one('#__clipContent')
innerHTML = clipContent.decode_contents()

newSoup = BeautifulSoup(innerHTML , 'html.parser') 
title = newSoup.select_one("h3.se_textarea")
photo_links = newSoup.select("div.se_viewArea img")

print('Title: ', title.text.strip())
for img in photo_links:
    print(img['data-src'])
```

Comment: you're welcome, don't forget to mark the the answer as accepted.